# How to convert multiples arrays into multiple columns Spark in Scala

Tags: arrays, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm pretty new in Scala, and I'm trying to read a json file that contains nested document which I converted into a spark table in order to access to their inner values, which return the following schema.

```
root
 |-- id: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: long (containsNull = true)
 |-- column1: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: double (containsNull = true)
 |-- column2: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: double (containsNull = true)
 |-- column3: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: double (containsNull = true)
 |-- column4: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: double (containsNull = true)
```

```
+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
|             id     |   column1          | column2            | column3            |    column4         |
+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
|[1163903, 1135067...|[3.7049873, 3.084...|[3.8597548, 4.188...|[1.6563705, 1.609...|[3.6857932, 3.190...|
+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
```

Which is not what I expected, I tried to explode all the columns but isn't returning what I expect either,

```
  val exploded = selectedAttributes.columns.foldLeft(selectedAttributes)((selectedAttributes, column) => selectedAttributes.withColumn(column, explode(col(column))))
```

```
|  id   |       column1   | column2       |     column3   |     column4    |
+-------+-----------------+-------------------+-------------------+----------------+
|1163903|        3.7049873|          3.8597548|          1.6563705|       3.6857932|
|1163903|        3.7049873|          3.8597548|          1.6563705|        3.190083|
|1163903|        3.7049873|          3.8597548|          1.6563705|        1.990814|
|1163903|        3.7049873|          3.8597548|          1.6563705|        2.319732|
|1163903|        3.7049873|          3.8597548|          1.6563705|       3.3546507|
|1163903|        3.7049873|          3.8597548|          1.6563705|        2.370629|
|1163903|        3.7049873|          3.8597548|          1.6563705|            null|
```

So I decide to collect information in the driver (*which I don't think is the best solution*) and create the dataframe by myself calling the zip function and creating a dataset, but isn't working either.

Something like this:

```
val zipFeatures = id zip column1 zip column4 zip column2 zip column3

case class dataset(id: Int, column1: Double, column2: Double, column3: Double, column4: Double) 
  val rowsOfFeatures = zipFeatures map {
    case ((((id, column1), column2), column3), column4) =>
      dataset(id, column1, column2, column3, column4)

  }

spark.createDataset(rowsOfFeatures).toDF()
```

Which give me a better result, however, I don't think I'll be available to save all this information into the driver.

Here is the expected output:

```
|id     |column1              | column2       | column3           | column4        |
|1163903|        3.7049873|          3.8597548|          1.6563705|       3.6857932|
|1135067|        3.0849733|          4.1883473|          1.6097081|        3.190083|
|1136137|         3.415591|            3.12623|          1.7889535|        1.990814|
|   1873|        2.6446266|          3.9076807|          2.0752525|        2.319732|
|1130327|          3.85075|           4.857642|           2.192937|       3.3546507|
|   1879|        2.7091007|          3.8000894|          2.0292222|        2.370629|
|  86684|         4.414381|          3.9849327|               null|            null|
|  66284|        3.3164778|           4.774783|          1.9173387|       3.1792257|
|   1652|        3.0772924|          3.4006166|          1.7305527|       2.9725764|
|1128385|         4.321163|           3.835489|               null|            null|
```

Any help would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using spark 2.4 or above versions, you can use the arrays_zip function and explode function, to get your desired result as shown below:

// Created a similar data frame of yours with the below code

```
val columnNames = List("id","col1","col2","col3","col4")

val arr = Seq((Array("1163903","1135067","1136137","1873","1130327","1879","86684","66284","1652","1128385"),Array("3.7049873","3.0849733", "3.415591","2.6446266","3.85075","2.7091007","4.414381","3.3164778","3.0772924","4.321163"),Array("3.8597548","4.1883473","3.12623","3.9076807","4.857642","3.8000894","3.9849327","4.774783","3.4006166","3.835489"),Array("1.6563705","1.6097081","1.7889535","2.0752525","2.192937","2.0292222","","1.9173387","1.7305527"),Array("3.6857932","3.190083","1.990814","2.319732","3.3546507","2.370629","","3.1792257","2.9725764")))

val df = sc.parallelize(arr).toDF( columnNames: _*)
df.printSchema
df.show
```

[image]

// using arrays_zip and explode function to get your desired result as below

```
val df2 = df.withColumn("newCol",arrays_zip(col("id"),col("col1"),col("col2"),col("col3"),col("col4"))).withColumn("newCol",explode(col("newCol"))).selectExpr("newCol.id as id", "newCol.col1 as col1", "newCol.col2 as col2", "newCol.col3 as col3", "newCol.col4 as col4")

df2.printSchema

df2.show
```

[image]